# iOS emulator starts with a empty blue screen

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Good day, I recently developed a simple ios application using Xamarin forms, However when I run the application through an iOS emulator a blank blue screen appears and then closes after a few seconds. But when I click on the app icon in the emulator again, it goes to the required screen (Main Page).

[image: Emulator screen]
[image: App screen]

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new MainPage();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the LaunchScreen, for default, has the Xamarin Image.

You can change it in the LaunchScreen.Storyboard, you can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=windows)

Comment: Is there a way to not show it and go straight to the main page, because I deleted the storyboard from the solutions explorer. My asset catalog also shows 'non set' as the launch screen.

Comment: You'll find it's a core requirement of iOS Guidelines

https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/launch-screen/